# Getting ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR on file download on Specific environment

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-service-fabric, http2, angular10, http-1.1

I have WebApi in .net core 3.1 and front end as angular application

I have written the below code for large file download from WebApi.

Both WebApi and Angular UI are hosted on Azure service fabric.

When a request goes to WebApi for file download from UI, a large file is returned as a stream in the background but when the entire file is returned from API, the browser throws "ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR" in the console, and the file is not downloaded in browser.

We have Azure and Onpremise(both on service fabric) as 2 different environments. The same code is working fine on Azure but not on OnPremise. In case of OnPremise URL also, file download works fine when accessing from the virtual machine but when the same URL is accessed from the United States machine, it does not work.

WebApi Code

[image]

Angular Code

[image]

We have also observed that when accessing URL from VM, protocol is http/1.1 and when from US machine where error appears is H2

[image]

Browser Error

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy (like Nginx) on-prem? If so, is it configured to allow such large requests, or to compress output (making the content-length invalid)?

Comment: Yes, there is a reverse proxy used. Need to check if any such restriction on it.